# How do I unadd a not yet committed file I have added?

Tags: mercurial

I typed in hg add and I am brand new to mercurial and the result of this was a bunch of dll's exe's pdb's etc all got added
Nothing's been committed yet and I basically want to undo the add. 
the documentation for hg forget is not very clear not sure if that is want I want
How do I undo the add before the next commit

I do have some real files that need adding so after I can undo the add I will use add with the exclude flag
Thanks

Comment: You can also use a `.hgignore` file to prevent accidentally adding certain types of files in the future as well.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Check out [this mercurial tip](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Undo_an_.27.60hg_add.60.27). To cite the link - if you have accidentally added a file, the way to undo that (changing its status from A back to ?, or unknown) is hg revert. For example, if you just ran hg add and realized that you do not want files foo or bar to be tracked by Mercurial:

```
hg revert foo bar
```

Comment: +1. Would have been better if you also provided the command itself, though.

Comment: I don't like to repeat something already written(professional decease I guess :-) ) - the command is added now.

Answer (score 13):

Either `revert` or `remove` can be used to un-add not yet commited stuff.  However, they both have other uses too, so for clarity `hg forget` was (re-)added in 1.3, and despite its name it might be easier to remember.

Comment: "and despite its name it might be easier to remember."... !!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Unix like system i believe the best option is to run

`hg status -an0 | xargs -0 hg revert`

Answer (score -4):

Two tips for these sorts of situations:

- If nothing has been commited at all, just delete .hg and start over with hg init.
- If you do something terrible to your repository and can't seem to figure out how to undo it, (and hg update -C or revert all won't fix), consider cloning the repository at the last good spot.